# Regular expression to determine if text has no more than n occurrences of a word

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file and I'm trying to detect if the number of occurences of the word "Warning:" is above a certain number, say 1000.

I have tried several attempts similar to the following, but I'm not getting a match I expect

```
"\\bWarning:{1000,}+ "
```

Comment: Do you need to count occurrences or just the number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your {1000,} is only matching the : character.  Also, the "+" in this case is superfluous.  You want it to match "Warning" and stuff in between, so you have to specify all of that:

```
"(?:\\bWarning:.*?){1000,}"
```

This reads: *"Starting from a non-word token, find the characters 'Warning:' and zero or more of anything until the next allowed match, 1000 or more times."*

Note the use of a non-capturing group (the `(?: )` construct) to specify what you want to match your N times.

You will also need to turn on single line matching (making `.` includes `\n`).

Comment: +1, but you can remove the comma so the regex engine may stop after having found 1000 `Warnings`. And to turn on single-line matching, just add `(?s)` to the start of the regex.

Comment: That looks like it would be very slow, especially when there are fewer than 1000 matches to be found.

Comment: This should be no more than O(N) time to scan a string: the .*? is a very efficient modifier in most regex engines.  It's conceptually the same as your example, except only requires one line.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to consider a non java/regex solution, you could get a **line count** in *NIX with:

```
grep "Warning:" YOURFILE.LOG | wc -l
```

Windows command line version of that would be:

```
find /c "Warning:" YOURFILE.log
```

Comment: +1 as it helped me with a teamcity feature that doesn't quite work how I expected

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're making this harder than it needs to be.  Why not just call `find()` in a loop and keep a tally of the hits?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bWarning:")
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
int hits = 0;
while (m.find())
{
  hits++;
}
```

I'm assuming the whole document is in a string.  Another possibility is to open the file with a Scanner and use its [`findWithinHorizon()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20int%29) method:

```
while (scanner.findWithinHorizon(p, 0) != null)
{
  hits++;
}
```